# Deselecting rows in table using jquery

Tags: jquery

In [this code](http://jsfiddle.net/hKZqS/51/), if I press shift+down key it selects multiple rows and if I press the up key, it is deselecting. But if I press shift+uparrow only deselection should happen.

Normally using the up and down keys, I can navigate up and down.

eg:If table has 10 rows and using shift+downarrow, I select 3 rows, and after this I press the down arrow to row 6. From this I should be able to select rows again with deselection the previous selected rows.

In my code you can see

```
if(code == 13) { //Enter keycode
    alert(did);
    if(did != undefined){
        window.open('keyboard.php?q=' + did);
    }
}
```

Here, if I press the enter key, it should take me to another page but for some reason I am getting an undefined error.  What am I doing wrong?

Comment: I am getting a JS error on event because you are switching between e and event.

Comment: Works for me after changing event to e since you are referencing the event with e.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the issue appears to be how the script is setting `did`

```
$(document).keyup(function(e) {
    var current = rows.filter(".ui-selected"),
        selected = $(); //an empty jQuery object
    ...
            case 13:
                var code = (e.keyCode ? e.keyCode : e.which);
                var did = current.data('docID');
    ...
}
```

since you're watching for `keyUp` events on the `document` the `document` is what is passed in as `this` in the event call

`var did = $(this).data('docID');`

you should be able to replace `$(this)` with `current` to get the desired effect

`var did = current.data('docID');`

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using typeof(did) != 'undefined'

Your error is here:

```
if (event.shiftKey) {
        selected = selected.add(current);
    }
```

should be e not event.  Works for me except that the page is not found when pressing enter, but the event works.

http://jsfiddle.net/hKZqS/61/ -> working fiddle

Comment: put your answer in my fiddle and update it.I have given my source code.